# Not sure how to make this option element return month range (*ngFor angular equivalent in react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this sample angular code here. It returns month range from month Jan to Aug

```
  months = [{month: 'Jan', value: '0'},
  {month: 'Feb', value: '1'},
  {month: 'Mar', value: '2'},
  {month: 'Apr', value: '3'},
  {month: 'May', value: '4'},
  {month: 'Jun', value: '5'},
  {month: 'Jul', value: '6'},
  {month: 'Aug', value: '7'}];

<div style="margin-left: auto">
  <select [(ngModel)]="from" style="width: 150px;height: 30px;">
    <option *ngFor="let m of months" [value]='m.value'>{{m.month}}</option>
  </select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;

<select [(ngModel)]="toMonth" style="width: 150px;height: 30px;">
  <option *ngFor="let m1 of months" [value]='m1.value'>{{m1.month}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

...somewhat like this
[image]
[image]
I am not sure how to implement the same in React...
I implemented it as follows in React...it's returning the error: 'months' is not defined

```
    <div>
  <select id="from">
     {
       months.map(el => <option value={el} key={el}> {el} 
       </option>)
     }
  </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <select id="toMonth">
     {
       months.map(el => <option value={el} key={el}> {el} 
       </option>)
     }
  </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;     
</div>
```

I defined months in props as a constant

Comment: can you attach your whole react codebase?

Comment: if it is in the props, then access 'props.month'

Comment: here's the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-liskov-em26c?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change all month itrations to this.state.month.map(...) and return {el.month}

```
<select id="from">
    {this.state.months.map((el) => (
      <option value={el.value} key={el}>
        {" "}
        {el.month}{" "}
      </option>
    ))}
</select>
```

Comment: hi, i am trying to implement a months filter in the same app with the applyDateFilter() function. As far as what I tried, it's only returning data from Jan to Jan, no matter what month range I select. Asked the same earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783425/months-range-filter-react  , haven't gotten any response yet

Comment: @anushka il have a look at that